# for loop only printing last item (C)

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Hello I am trying to write a C program that basically takes in a structure, stores it in an array, and then prints that structure in this format:

Lastname, Firstname \n
Grade: B

for every item added into the array, now the problem I am having is only the last item that is added is being printed. I know this is happening in the for loop because the code is executing and printing. I am not going to post the entire program because it is a lot of code so I will just put what is important.

```
void add(char* student_firstname, char* student_lastname, char* student_grade, char* student_level, struct student* list)
{

    int i;
    for (i = count-1; i < count; i++){
        if ((strcmp(list[i].lastName, student_lastname) != 0) && (strcmp(list[i].firstName, student_firstname) != 0)){
            strcpy(list[i].firstName, student_firstname);
            strcpy(list[i].lastName, student_lastname);
            strcpy(list[i].grade, student_grade);
        }
        else{
            printf("This student is already on the list!");
        }
        //count++;
    }
    printf("Student added!");
}
```

The count variable was set to 0 before. 
*don't worry about the student_grade

display() function for reference:

```
void display()
{
    int i;
    for (i = count-1; i < count; i++){
        printf("%s, %s \n", list[i].lastName, list[i].firstName);
        printf("Grade: %s \n", list[i].grade);
    }
}
```

Also here is my read() function:

```
void read()
{
    char student_firstName[100];
    char student_lastName[100];
    char student_grade[30];
    char student_level[100];

    printf("\nEnter the student's first name:\n");
    fgets(student_firstName, sizeof(student_firstName), stdin);

    printf("\nEnter the student's last name:\n");
    fgets(student_lastName, sizeof(student_lastName), stdin);

    printf("\nEnter the student's grade (A+,A,A-,...):\n");
    fgets(student_grade, sizeof(student_grade), stdin);

    printf("\nEnter the student's education level (f/so/j/s):\n");
    fgets(student_level, sizeof(student_level), stdin);

    // discard '\n' chars attached to input; NOTE: If you are using GCC, you may need to comment out these 4 lines
    student_firstName[strlen(student_firstName) - 1] = '\0';
    student_lastName[strlen(student_lastName) - 1] = '\0';
    student_grade[strlen(student_grade) - 1] = '\0';
    student_level[strlen(student_level) - 1] = '\0';

    add(student_firstName, student_lastName, student_grade, student_level, list);
    printf("\n"); // newline for formatting
}
```

Comment: @MasterDNE -- your algo checking for duplicates is broken, and that is your problem...

Answer (score 2):

Look at the line:

```
for (i = count-1; i < count; i++)
```

in both your add and display functions. This goes from count-1 to count, meaning it only ever prints/adds one item at position count-1. You should get rid of the for loop in the add function, increment count, and rewrite the print function to go from 0 to count. This should fix all of the issues you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Your algo for checking for duplicates in `add` is broken.  I need to look more like this, but you should add error checking and protection for bufferoverflow as well.

```
void add(char* student_firstname, char* student_lastname, char* student_grade, char* student_level, struct student* list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if ((strcmp(list[i].lastName, student_lastname) == 0) &&      
            (strcmp(list[i].firstName, student_firstname) == 0)) {
            printf("This student is already on the list!");
            return;
        }
    }
    strcpy(list[count].firstName, student_firstname);
    strcpy(list[count].lastName, student_lastname);
    strcpy(list[count].grade, student_grade);
    count++;
    printf("Student added!");
}
```

First you need to add protection from that `count` does not get too big.

Second you need to stop using `strcpy` and use `strncpy` instead so as to avoid buffer overflow errors.

Third, you may want to avoid using a linear scan, and figure out how to use a index of some kind, but for a school project that is probably not important.

Similar in your `display` function, you should adjust the for loop if you expect it to print out all the records, or eliminate the loop if it is only supposed to print the last record.